# Can anyone help me with Twitter?

Tags: php, javascript, twitter, twitter-oauth

My website is allow user tweet request to twitter. When they click on tweet, default text of the request will come out, and user can also edit it. Below is sample source code:

**Code**

```
$tweet="Hello, everybody";

<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" id="id" 
data-text="'.$tweet.'" data-lang="ja" data-size="large" data-count="none" 
data-url="none">Tweet</a>

<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;
js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs); 
}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
```

If user change text from "Hello, everybody" to the text that they want, so can i get the text that user change after tweet or not?

Thank in advance.

Comment: I'm not really to sure what your trying to say here.  Can you please clarify?

Comment: @it means that, when user tweet request on my site, so when they click on tweet button, twitter box will appear with the default of request that user click in the twitter box. User can edit it to what they want, so how can i get the last text in twitter box or not?

Answer (score -1):

First idea that comes to my mind (that actually rather seems like a 'quick hack') is registering a new onclick listener to the 'send tweet' button. You could try and get the value of the textarea and send it to php via an ajax-request.

something like:

```
function my_onclick() {
   var text = $(selector for textare).innerHTML();
   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: url,
      data: text,
      success: success,
      dataType: dataType
   });
```

I know I did it like this once... but this is probably not the most elegant way to do it!